# Python shapely: Aggregating points to shape files for a Choropleth map

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, choropleth, r-tree

I'm trying a create a Choropleth in Python3 using shapely, fiona & bokeh for display.

I have a file with about 7000 lines that have the location of a town and a counter.

Example:

```
54.7604;9.55827;208
54.4004;9.95918;207
53.8434;9.95271;203
53.5979;10.0013;201
53.728;10.2526;197
53.646;10.0403;196
54.3977;10.1054;193
52.4385;9.39217;193
53.815;10.3476;192
...
```

I want to show these in a 12,5km grid, for which a shapefile is available on 
https://opendata-esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3c1f46241cbb4b669e18b002e4893711_0

The code I have works.

It's very slow, because it's a brute force algorithm that checks each of the 7127 grid points against all of the 7000 points.

```
import pandas as pd
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon
from shapely.prepared import prep
sf = r'c:\Temp\geo_de\Hexagone_125_km\Hexagone_125_km.shp'
shp = fiona.open(sf)

district_xy = [ [ xy for xy in feat["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]] for feat in shp] 
district_poly = [ Polygon(xy) for xy in district_xy] # coords to Polygon

df_p = pd.read_csv('points_file.csv', sep=';', header=None)
df_p.columns = ('lat', 'lon', 'count')

map_points = [Point(x,y) for x,y in zip(df_p.lon, df_p.lat)] # Convert Points to Shapely Points

all_points = MultiPoint(map_points) # all points

def calc_points_per_poly(poly, points, values): # Returns total for poly
    poly = prep(poly)
    return sum([v for p, v in zip(points, values) if poly.contains(p)])

# this is the slow part
# for each shape this sums um the points

sum_hex = [calc_points_per_poly(x, all_points, df_p['count']) for x in district_poly]
```

Since this is extremly slow, I'm wondering if there is a faster way to get the *num_hex* value, especially, since the real world list of points may be a lot larger and a smaller grid with more shapes would deliver a better result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using 'geopandas' and its built-in rtree spatial index. It allows you to do the check only if there is a possibility that point lies within polygon.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

sf = 'Hexagone_125_km.shp'
shp = gpd.read_file(sf)

df_p = pd.read_csv('points_file.csv', sep=';', header=None)
df_p.columns = ('lat', 'lon', 'count')

gdf_p = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_p, geometry=[Point(x,y) for x,y in zip(df_p.lon, df_p.lat)])

sum_hex = []
spatial_index = gdf_p.sindex

for index, row in shp.iterrows():
    polygon = row.geometry
    possible_matches_index = list(spatial_index.intersection(polygon.bounds))
    possible_matches = gdf_p.iloc[possible_matches_index]
    precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.within(polygon)]
    sum_hex.append(sum(precise_matches['count']))

shp['sum'] = sum_hex
```

This solution should be faster than your. You can then plot your GeoDataFrame via Bokeh. If you want more details on spatial indexing I recommend this article by Geoff Boeing: https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/

Comment: Works and is about 15x faster than my brute force. I managed to plot this using the "sum_hex" list, but not directly from the geopanda frame. Can you point me to an example on how to print a GeoDataFrame directly via Bokeh?

Comment: I've never used Bokeh personally, so I can just point you towards https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson5-interactive-map-bokeh.html . It might be actually useful to add Bokeh example to geopandas docs.